# editorgrid as variable is not editable

Tags: extjs

In my application, I´m creating several modal windows which contains a form and an editorgrid. In order to re-use the components, I´ve created the combos, fieldtext, checkbox and other stuff as variables, and only add the necesarry to each window. One of those variables is an editorgrid, xtype: 'editorgrid', and there is the issue:

If I add the variable myEditorGrid to the panel, it works OK the first time I open the window, but the second time that any window has to render the same editorgrid, then the fields cannot be edited any more.

If I create the editorgrid inside the panel (and don´t use the variable), then it works OK everytime I open the window, but I need to copy&paste the same code over and over to all the windows, and that´s not very professional.

I thought the problem is that the variable is not destroyed, and made sure that the windows is closed, but I don´t know how to destroy the variable, and even if this is the solution.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code for one of these as an example? I've had the same issue before when trying to re-use a column model across different grids

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse an `EditorGrid` in this manner, because it's column model gets destroyed after use.

The best way to reuse a component is to use the `Ext.extend` method [described here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual%3aComponent%3aExtending_Ext_Components), and then in your `initComponent` have something like..

```
initComponent : function() {
    this.cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns: [
          //define columns here
        ]
    });
    this.ds = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        //store config
    });
    //...
}
```